# Using ADODB within Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-connection, adodb

I'm trying to use adodb connection withing access vba, and it doesn't return me anydata, I guess my problem would be the connection, even though i'm using CurrentProject.Connection.

Need help please, here is my code

```
Dim cnThisConnect As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsExpenses As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sQuery As String

    sQuery = "SELECT  [ShippingSoldPrice] , ShippingPurchaseTaxe FROM Vehicles LEFT JOIN Contacts AS C ON 
    Vehicles.CustomerID = C.ID"
    sQuery = sQuery & " Where " & Me.Filter

     Set cnThisConnect = CurrentProject.Connection

     rsExpenses.Open sQuery, cnThisConnect, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    If Not rsExpenses.EOF Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the line containing the where clause maybe this is the problem

```
'sQuery = sQuery & " Where " & Me.Filter
```

then check the returning records, if there are records then the problem is in the filter conditions.

Hope this may help

Comment: for example `LIKE` operator: `*` of DAO is `%` for ADO